# setting TextView's text style to TextAppearance.Appcompat... programmatically

Tags: android, text-styling

I have been using:

```
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title"
```

in my layout xml, but this time i want to set text style programmatically from java code.
But this code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title);
    } else {
        textView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title);
    }
```

doesn't compile. It says 'Cannot resolve symbol 'TextAppearance'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'` in your dependencies? (in your build.gradle file)

If so, try using `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_SearchResult_Title` as resource id.

Comment: 'Field requires API level 21. Any way to get it working on API16+?

Comment: 'The resource is marked as 'private'. I guess i'll have to copy-paste the styles i need into my project's styles. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's just a Lint message. It will still do what you're asking for.